# Comparing Strings in C Macros (for MODULE_LICENSE)

Tags: macros, linux-device-driver, c-preprocessor

I'd like to be able to ensure I don't accidentally statically link any proprietary modules into the kernel.  I was thinking of making `MODULE_LICENSE("Proprietary")` fail at compile time if MODULE was not defined.  (or even better, fail if `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL")` was not defined...).

But I can't find a good way to compare strings within a macro -- anyone have any good solutions to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this.

The way it's usually done is by defining preprocessor symbols, and comparing their (integer) values:

```
#define LICENSE_PROPRIETARY 1
#define LICENSE_GPL         2
#define LICENSE_MIT         3

#define MODULE_LICENSE      LICENSE_GPL

#if MODULE_LICENSE != LICENSE_GPL
#error "Not GPL, fail fail"
#endif
```